# Let's clean up [friendship]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request

[friendship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/friendship) seems like it's highly unnecessary on Stack Overflow, it has [113 Questions (where none of them are improved by the tag) and no tag Wiki.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/friendship)

According to the [Burnination-Request rules - criteria #2](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239190/when-to-burninate/239191#239191) I request this tag to be deleted from SO because it is blatantly off topic on the site.

We should probably kill it with fire.

For friend classes in object oriented programming, the [friend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/friend) can be used, already exists, and has a tag wiki.

Answers about these specific classes will then have to be re-tagged.

I came across this tag because of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33341314/friendship-or-relationship) blatantly off topic question by the way, and I was surprised by "There is a tag for *that*?!"

Comment: It has been used mainly for OOP and C++ questions. Out of 112 questions, 40 questions use both `[C++]` and `[friendship]` tags. Question is should we simply remove the tag from the 112 questions or retag them? In which case, retag with what?

Comment: @AzizShaikh I don't believe that this tag needs an replacement, and I find it entirely superficial. I'd say just remove it entirely. Most questions have a descriptive title, so more then the [C++] would be sufficient.

Comment: [This search](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/friendship+-friend+-friend-function) is the questions with friendship but without [tag:friend] or [tag:friend-function]. There's 11 that are tagged with some friendly combination. Side note: [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33306076) is _really_ hoping it can be your buddy.

Comment: Related tags: [tag:friend] (as you already mentioned), [tag:friend-function] & [tag:friend-class] (more-or-less synonymous with [tag:friend]), and a set of social-networking tags [tag:facebook-friends], [tag:facebook-invite-friends], [tag:google-friend-connect], [tag:friendfeed], and [tag:friendrequest]. Your proposal needs to be broadened to include evaluation and guidance for all these as well, or it won't really improve things.

Comment: The [SOCVR](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) is preparing to take this on, following [this process](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/324071/578411).

Comment: The title should be "Time to unfriend [friendship]?"

Comment: @JDB it almost [was](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/308792/5) but there is a notice in the post that states: *Please don't edit post title while it has featured tag.*. And I don't think the title really matters to decide if the tag should be removed.

Comment: SO is destroying friendship.

Comment: @nnrales SOs always do.

Comment: I'm sorry, but i see you only as a burnination request: burn-zoned

Comment: The title should be "Should we end our [friendship]?"

Comment: @mbomb007 read the link at the top of the question about the process.  Punny titles are removed when the question is promoted to the featured status.

Comment: Yes please , everyone friend-zoned me.

Comment: @DanNeely So...?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

## Progress on CLEAN-UP

You can help out by reviewing the questions and answers in these tags to clean-up the edges and:

- flag or close questions that are duplicate/off-topic/unclear/too broad/opinion based;
- filter on these tags in the Close Vote Queue and review;
- vote on the questions and its answers;
- delete vote the question or answer(s) if there is nothing of value;
- editing to add value,

  - Questions related to other programming `friend` concepts can be retagged with tags like **[friend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/friend)** or **[friend-function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/friend-function)**.
  - Questions related to social network (profile connection / scraping) can be retagged with **[social-network-friendship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/social-network-friendship)**.
- flag obsolete comments.

Here are some easy links to get you started: [friendship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/friendship)

- [Open](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfriendship%5D+closed%3Afalse) 0
- [Closed](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfriendship%5D+closed%3Atrue) 0
- [No answers](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfriendship%5D+closed%3Afalse+answers%3A0) 0
- [No accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfriendship%5D+closed%3Afalse+hasaccepted%3Afalse) 0

[Review in the Close vote Queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=friendship)

Remember that we don't want to destroy value so let salvaging a post be your first priority! If you have specific questions feel free to drop in to the [SOCVR](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers), or leave a comment under this post.

Comment: Battleship... burninated!

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/ihN3m.png

Answer (score 43):

Not so fast.

From looking through the examples, it's pretty clear there are two distinct use-cases, as @Mogsdad said:

1. friendship/social network connection (frameworks, profiles,
   scraping, etc.)
2. [friend-class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/friend-class)/[friend-function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/friend-function), exclusively in
   C++, and essentially unknown outside it

They're pretty clear and distinct, and the tags do add information (as much as any other tag describing the end-application, e.g. [accounting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/accounting) or [minecraft](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/minecraft)). 1. has gradually become more important than 2. over the last decade or two, and since they're from very different language/scripting communities (Rails/PHP/C#/etc.), there's a lot of accidental use of [friend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/friend) by the 1. crowd, because they're oblivious to the old meaning 2. So there's a growing case for renaming [friend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/friend), but even with a name like [friend-function], it'll still be misunderstood by the 1. crowd (*"here is my function for finding friends using script X on social network Y"*). So really it would have to be  called **[c++-friend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b-friend)**

I agree tag [friendship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/friendship) is also ambiguously named, needs renaming to something like **[social-network-friendship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/social-network-friendship)**.

Comment: Well. 220 of 900 [tag:friend]-questions are not about C++ or C++/CLI: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/friend%20-c%2b%2b%20-c%2b%2b11%20-c%2b%2b-cli Some of them are about emulating that feature in other languages though...

Comment: Can confirm, never heard of friend function before today :D

Comment: @Deduplicator: that query turns up questions without tag [tag:friend]. Can you fix its syntax?

Comment: On the other hand, does the [tag:friendship] tag actually bring anything useful to a question? I really don't think so.

Comment: @DavidG: I just said it depends on which of the two senses that is being applied. Where 'friendship' means 'social network connection' (frameworks, profiles, scraping, etc.) then yes it describes the purpose of the application. Just as much as, say, [tag:accounting].

Comment: @Holt: I already suggested [tag:friendship] needed renaming to something like [tag:social-network-friendship]. Whether each individual question further needs tags for individual social networks (facebook/twitter/mahout/etc.) is a separate issue, I don't think we need to solve that here.

Comment: @smci: The query is ok, but you are on that horribly broken *new-nav*. Anyway, adding a query-operator circumvents the new-navs mess in this case: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfriend%5D+-%5Bc%2B%2B%5D+-%5Bc%2B%2B11%5D+-%5Bc%2B%2B-cli%5D+is%3Aq

Comment: Update: The reloaded new-nav seems to work out.

Comment: What if someone created a [usage-guidance](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/friendship/info) for [tag:friendship]? It would help users decide upon which tag to use, imho.

Comment: @smci There are currently [62 questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/friendship) with the `frienship` tag, if I removed all the questions tagged with `facebook`, `twitter`, `linkedin` or `social-networking`, I still get [47 questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/friendship%20and%20not%20twitter%20and%20not%20facebook%20and%20not%20linkedin%20and%20not%20social-networking). So your tag renaming will only work for 25% of the questions tagged with `friendship`, since all the other are mostly related to database relationship without any social network involved.

Comment: @GuiImamura but [people don't read the tag excerpts because we don't swat them into their faces](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/256114)

Comment: And not that I encourage the use of the language, but VB.NET uses the `friend` in place of `internal` (for C#) for access restrictions

Comment: Relevant: [Friend Assemblies (C# and Visual Basic)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0tke9fxk.aspx)

Comment: @ChrisBeck I have now lol.

Comment: @smci "social-networking" would make more sense than "friendship" for describing the *purpose of a piece of software*, though. The analogue for "friendship" isn't "accounting," it's some specific *element* of accounting software, e.g. "depositing." "Depositing" wouldn't be an appropriate tag, either.